# Difficulty echoing error message if mysql query returns nothing PEAR PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pear, mdb2

I am struggling to echo an error message stating 'No results' when my mysql query returns nothing. I am using PEAR. Here is what I have at the moment.

```
while($rows =& $output->fetchRow()) {
if (numRows($query)== 0){
   echo 'No results';
}
else {
 echo 'data found';
}

}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks for checking out my question.

Answer (score 2):

If there are no results, `fetchRow` won't return anything, which means the loop doesn't get executed at all, which means the code inside the loop won't either. The logic is:

```
if numRows == 0
    echo error
else
    while fetchRow
        echo result
```

Comment: Ok thanks for your response. I have tried this logic and cant get it to work. Could you help me out please?

Comment: Please update your question with more code then if you require an answer with actual code. It's hard to guess what's what from the small snippet you're showing.